# Hybrid Parallel Programming using OpenMPI and OpenMP : OpenMP threads always use 1 out of 4 cores per node

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp, openmpi, hybrid

I have created a home cluster using 3 Raspberry PI boards to learn and experiment with Hybrid Parallel programming.
My setup is as follows:-
1 RPi3 B+ (4 cores ) and 2 RPi4 (4 cores each)and all these nodes are connected over ethernet using a switch. Therefore, in total I have 12 cores in my cluster. RPI3B+ is designated as node1 and rest of the two RPI4 boards as node2 and node 3 respectively.

I have written a simple program using OpenMPI and OpenMP, which sums up two large vectors.

The structure of the code is as follows:-
My intention here is - I would start 3 MPI processes with ranks 0, 1, and 2 and bind them to node1, node2, and node 3 respectively. From the inside of each MPI process, I would start 4 OMP threads which would do their job of summing up the distributed vector chunks and return back the result to rank 0.

Although the code is working and giving the correct result, but my observation is that the OMP threads are not leveraging all the CPU cores present in a node. Using htop, I have noticed that only 1 core on each of the nodes is 100% loaded.

The way I am launching the program is as follows:-
#mpirun --map-by node --display-devel-map --hostfile nodeconfig -np 3 ./addVectorsMPIHybrid 3000000 3000000

The nodeconfig contains just names of the nodes i.e, node1, node2 and node3

Please note: I have verified that 4 omp threads are getting created in the #pragma parallel section.

Can someone please give me pointers - why OMP threads are not running on all the cores?

The code that I am running:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double *v1, *v2, *resulv;
    double *v1local, *v2local, *resulvlocal;

    double startTime, endTime;

    int rank, size;
    int local_n;
    int n;
    int root = 0;
    int provided;

    if(argc <2)
    {
        printf("Please provide correct inputs\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    n = atoi(argv[1]);
    if(n <=0)
    {
        printf("Please enter valid size of vector\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    //MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Init_thread(NULL, NULL, MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED, &provided);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    local_n = n/size;

    if(rank == 0)
    {
        v1 = (double *) malloc (sizeof(double) *  n);
        assert(v1);
        
        v2 = (double *) malloc (sizeof(double) *  n);
        assert(v2);
        
        resulv = (double *) malloc (sizeof(double) *  n);   
        assert(resulv);

        resulv[n] = {0};
        
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
            v1[i] = v2[i] = (double)i;
    }

    v1local = (double *) malloc (sizeof(double) *  local_n);
    assert(v1local);
    
    v2local = (double *) malloc (sizeof(double) *  local_n);
    assert(v2local);

    resulvlocal = (double *) malloc (sizeof(double) *  local_n);   
    assert(resulv);

    resulvlocal[local_n] = {0.0};

    startTime = MPI_Wtime();

    //Scatter v1
    MPI_Scatter(v1, local_n,MPI_DOUBLE, v1local, local_n, MPI_DOUBLE, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Scatter(v2, local_n,MPI_DOUBLE, v2local, local_n, MPI_DOUBLE, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);


    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4) default(none) shared(resulvlocal, v1local, v2local) firstprivate(local_n)
    {
        #pragma omp single
        {
            printf("num_threads = %d\n", omp_get_num_threads());
        }
        #pragma omp for
        for(int i=0; i<local_n; i++)
            resulvlocal[i] = v1local[i] + v2local[i];
    }
    MPI_Gather(resulvlocal, local_n, MPI_DOUBLE, resulv, local_n, MPI_DOUBLE, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    endTime = MPI_Wtime();



    if(rank == 0)
    {
        //Display resulv
        #if 0
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
            printf("%0.3f ",resulv[i]);
        printf("\n");
        #endif
        
        printf("Time taken to compute is:%f in sec\n",endTime-startTime);

        free(v1);
        free(v2);
        free(resulv);
    }

    free(v1local);
    free(v2local);
    free(resulvlocal);

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please give more details about how you compile your simple program and what compilers you're using? That will help understand what might be going wrong and propose a way to fix your code.  Maybe even a short, compilable piece of code that just wastes a few cycles would be helpful.

Comment: Compilation step: mpic++ -Wall -fopenmp addVectorsMPIHybrid.cpp -o addVectorsMPIHybrid

Comment: g++ -I/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include/openmpi -I/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include -pthread -L/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib -lmpi_cxx -lmpi

Comment: @Hello Michael, I have pasted the code. The g++ version is : g++ (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, ompi version is - 3.1.3, _OPENMP 201511

Comment: Try adding `--bind-to none` in your mpirun command line

Comment: @Hello Gilles, I added  "--bind-to" none to "mpirun" but it is not having any effect. The htop on the nodes still show only one out of the available 4 cores getting 100% utilized. It seems that although multiple OMP threads i.e, 4 here as per my code, are getting spawned in the "#pragma parallel" region but all these OMP threads seem to time share on any one core out of availbale 4.

Comment: Just to add one observation - when I ran a OMP application (i.e, not Hybrid) with 4 OMP threads spawned, I could observe that all the OMP threads ran on all the 4 cores of node1 as expected. However, when I ran the above program with only 1 MPI process with 4 OMP threads, I could observe that all the 4 OMP threads time shared any 1 of the 4 cores with that core getting 100% utilized.

Comment: There's typically nothing to do for the threads in you program, compared to what is to be done by the non-OpenMP part. Try beefing up the central part of your code (where the OpenMP threads are spawned) by for example looping over it for quite some iterations...

Comment: @Gilles, thanks for this input. I have added a dummy() function inside the OMP for loop, which does some dummy calculation. With this I notice that OMP threads in node 1, node 2 and node 3 briefly use 100% of all the cores. However, I would like to understand how do we force the OMP threads to always run on individual cores, irrespective of the job load on the OMP threads.